# Bootstrap 4 equivalent to CSS Inline-Grid

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have a list of items that I want to display on a desktop web page.

```
<div class="departments">
@foreach (var department in Model)
{
<div>
    <img src="department_photo.png" />
    <div class="details">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => department.Description)
    </div>
</div>
}
</div>
```

I would like to have it show up in a dynamic grid so that there are 3 columns that auto wrap around.  So if I had four items in the list it would look like

```
A B C
D
```

If I had 11 items it would look like

```
A B C
D E F
G H I
J K
```

In .CSS, I could do it like this:

```
.departments {
    display: inline-grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}
```

How would I do this in Bootstrap 4?  I want to use bootstrap to take advantage of the responsiveness.  I have not found a way to not have to separate the rows myself.

Comment: And why do you think that _Grid_ isn't suitable for responsive design?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong but isn't what you're requesting entirely possible with Bootstrap's [grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/grid/)? Bootstrap's layout is probably its most widely used feature and I believe it's one of the main reasons behind its popularity.

**Note:** ignore the CSS entirely, it's just to highlight each cell on hover.

```css
.col-4 {
  transition: background-color .3s ease-out;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.col-4:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">Item 1<br>second line</div>
    <div class="col-4">Item 2</div>
    <div class="col-4">Item 3</div>
    <div class="col-4">Item 4</div>
    <div class="col-4">Item 5<br>second line</div>
    <div class="col-4">Item 6</div>
    <div class="col-4">Item 7</div>
    <div class="col-4">Item 8</div>
    <div class="col-4">Item 9<br>second line</div>
    <div class="col-4">Item 10</div>
    <div class="col-4">Item 11</div>
    <div class="col-4">Item 12</div>
    <div class="col-4">Item 13<br>second line</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are totally right. When I tried that earlier, I left off the <div class="container-fluid"> & <div class="row"> and just went directly to the <div class=col-4>.  Thanks!

Comment: It's one of the very few Bootstrap *gotcha*'s and probably the only really important one. Always wrap `.col-*`s in `.row`s. You're quite welcome. Happy coding!